# SharePoint 2013 ListData.svc works for English language and fails for other languages

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, language, multilingual, user-information-list

We have SharePoint 2013 On premises multilingual site, To get the user details we are  using the below query to get the login user details from the **User Information list**

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList?$filter=(Id%20eq%20306)&$select=FirstName,LastName
```

The above query was working fine when you set the browser(Chrome) language to English. If we change the browser language to other like French etc.. , the above query returns below error

> Resource not found for the segment 'UserInformationList'.

Can any one help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, this endpoint is localized / translated. So you need to check the language and depending on the language you need to use the correctly translated endpoint.

Quote from: https://www.layer2solutions.com/support/cloud-connector-faqs/accessing-the-user-information-list

> Note that the collection name for this list is different based on regional settings of the SharePoint site. For example, the German name for this collection is "Benutzerinformationsliste". If you are unsure what the name is, you can load the base OData URI (http:///_vti_bin/listdata.svc​) into a browser and the resulting XML.